# What is my WCF RIA service uri?

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0, uri, ria

I'm very new to Silverlight and WCF RIA services so, excuse me for my misunderstandings.
I have a telerik map component in my SL client with uses tiles url from a map server. I wanted to implement my custom provider so, I implemented this method:

```
 protected override Uri GetTile(int tileLevel, int tilePositionX, int tilePositionY)
    {
        int zoomLevel = ConvertTileToZoomLevel(tileLevel);

        string url = this.tileUrlFormat;

        url = ProtocolHelper.SetScheme(url);
        url = url.Replace("{zoom}", zoomLevel.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        url = url.Replace("{x}", tilePositionX.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        url = url.Replace("{y}", tilePositionY.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
        url = url.Replace("{type}", googleTileType.ToString());
        return new Uri(url);
    }
```

It works with online map servers. But, I wanted to use my own tiles which are stored in a sql server database.

So, how can I do it? I mean how can I implement a WCF RIA service in my web project so that, my SL client call its url? I found many examples which define a domain service in web project and use it in SL, but, I want to know what is it's url? 
for example if I implement a domain service which get x , y, zoom parameters and retrieve it's tile from database, what is it's URL so that, I can call it in my SL component??
And I have another question. If it is possible to do so, Is it possible to authenticate my users for calling that service? and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use a WCF RIA Service to query the tile. You need to implement a get method on the server that receives the zoom parameters, x, y, and type, and return the appropriate image.

For example, if you use in the server ASP MVC, the get function is:

```
namespace MvcMap.Controllers
{
    public class MapTile : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetTile(int zoom, int x, int y, string type="")
        {
            // Add your action logic here
            // return your image
        }
    }
}
```

the url to call this MVC action is similar to:

http://yourdomain_or_ip/MapTile/GetTile?zoom=10&x=5&y10